# Alert infinito com .focus()

Tags: javascript

por que fica dando alert infinito quando tento focus() num campo onblur preenchido incorretamente?

```
if(ret = TstForDat(wCampo, "")!=""){
          alert('Data Incorreta! Favor preencher a data corretamente.');
          wCampo.focus(); //apos colocar isto, o alert em cima fica aparecendo sem parar.
}
```

Comment: Provavelmente porque o evento *blur* é disparado ao definir o novo foco.

Comment: Consegui resolver... Coloquei a data correta antes de setar o focus(). Obrigado Anderson!

Answer (score 0):

Isto ocorre porque o evento associado ao Onblur gera um alert e um focus, e, por sua vez, o evento focus aciona o Onblur novamente.

Resolvi este problema realizando um *work-around*:

```
    if(ret = TstForDat(wCampo, "")!=""){
          alert('Data Incorreta! Favor preencher a data corretamente.');
          wCampo.Value = '';
          wCampo.select();
    }
```